# Responds to, but not known?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is a slight follow on from a previous question:

```
for(id <stuffieProtocol> eachObject in stuffieArray) {
    if([eachObject respondsToSelector:@selector(secretID)]) [eachObject secretID];
}
```

The above is a line from a fast enumeration loop that takes a number of objects out of an `NSArray` and checks to see if they respond to the method `secretID`. The method `secretID` is not part of the `@protocol` but rather a method defined on one of the objects in the collection.

The `if` statement above fails because the compiler says `"No known instance method for selector secretID"` Which is fine, id does not care and the method is not defined in `<stuffieProtocol>` I can fix this by casting each object to the type that does define `secretID:`

```
if([eachObject respondsToSelector:@selector(secretID)]) [(Ted *)eachObject secretID];
```

My question is in the original code, how does the compiler know that `eachObject` responds to the method `secretID` but yet when you ask it to call that method its says "No known method" I am just a little curious about the mechanics?

Comment: Casting to `Ted *` makes me uneasy - I would prefer to cast to `id`, otherwise you are implicitly documenting that if the object responds to `secretID` then is must be an instance of `Ted`, which may not always hold true and you are potentially just trying to silence the compiler by lying to it. Casting to `id` will be fine as long as the compiler can see a header that declares the method e.g. you have imported a class that declares a method `secretID` like your `Ted` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know anything about whether the object responds to that selector but the runtime does.  (i.e. The compiler doesn't execute the code.)  The compiler only cares that any NSObject can respond to `respondsToSelector:`.

Comment: Ah I see, adding (Ted *) just tells the compiler where "secretID" is implemented, the respondsToSelector: does not come into play until runtime.